# add and remove objects from hashset in java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have Skills pojo class.SkillsParts is a string of array.Using skillsParts i am settings Skillsname.My Problem is that first time i set to null and then parse SkillsParts,Creating Skills new object & add it to set,then update.But i want avoid 
this if it is present then remove and if not present then add.

Pojo class

```
package com.cloudcodes.gdirectory.pojo;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Skills implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long skillId;
    private String skillName;
    private String skillDesc;
    private Long categoryId;

    public Long getSkillId() {
        return skillId;
    }

    public void setSkillId(Long skillId) {
        this.skillId = skillId;
    }

    public String getSkillName() {
        return skillName;
    }

    public void setSkillName(String skillName) {
        this.skillName = skillName;
    }

    public String getSkillDesc() {
        return skillDesc;
    }

    public void setSkillDesc(String skillDesc) {
        this.skillDesc = skillDesc;
    }

    public Long getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(Long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

}
```

This is my relation table

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private java.util.Set<Skills> skillsList = new HashSet<Skills>();
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/ajax/saveSkills.htm")
        public  @ResponseBody String saveSkills(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam String skills,@RequestParam String Email) throws IOException
        {

            Domain domain1 = (Domain)request.getSession().getAttribute("Domain");
            Long domanId =domain1.getDomainId();
            String[] skillsParts = skills.split(",");
            UserProfile user = userProfileManager.getUserByEmail(domain1.getPrimary_Domain_Id(), Email);

                /* Here is problem  */
            Set<Skills> remove = new HashSet<Skills>();
            user.setSkillsList(remove);
            for(int i =0;i<skillsParts.length;i++){

                Skills skillObj = new Skills();
                skillObj.setSkillName(skillsParts[i]);
                user.getSkillsList().add(skillObj);

            }
            userProfileManager.update(user);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.toJson(user);
        }
```

Comment: can you reframe your last line. It is not clear what you want to achieve. If SkillsList is a Set it will always have unique values.

Comment: yes Sir it contains unique value.i want to get previous value using getSkillsList method and then check using skillsParts string Array.If skillsParts value is present in previous list then remove it if not then add in previous list...

Comment: tried a solution below ...see if this you mean to do, although I am not very sure why will you want to do this

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you need to persist the pojo `Skills` in a table and define `equals()/hashCode()` for it. As far as I can see, the business key here is the name of the skill, so that's what you need to check. [Don't use the `skillId`!!](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch04.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode)

In the controller, you need to ask Hibernate for `Skills` by name instead of creating them yourself. If Hibernate can't find one, create a new one, persist it and add it to the hash. Hibernate will then do the right thing.

Comment: Sir i added above code but i got exception java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<Skills> remove = new HashSet<Skills>();
user.setSkillsList(remove);
```

is actually doing nothing apart than setting an empty set in the user SkillList.

```
for(int i =0;i<skillsParts.length;i++){

            Skills skillObj = new Skills();
            skillObj.setSkillName(skillsParts[i]);
            if(!user.getSkillsList().remove(skillObj)){ //1
              user.getSkillsList().add(skillObj);
            }
        }
```

*user.getSkillsList().remove(skillObj)* will return a boolean depending on the fact that if it is already present. If the set has skillObj it will remove it and the condition becomes false due to negative in the beginning else it will add it.

Comment: Sir i removed empty set code..But i have save button.Sir i want only those entries which is present in skillsParts  from previous List and new entry..for adding in SkillsList.So how can i do this..I tried ur code but duplicate entries found..

Comment: in Set no duplicate is stored but my Skillsid is autogenerated

Comment: @RaviChothe define a hashcode and equals method in the Skills class. make sure that Skillsid is NOT a part of both the functions.